# Tricky z-index stacking between 3 elements

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm sorry, but I'm not really sure how to properly explain this issue in the title.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: i'm trying to achieve this]

Here's what I have done, [I've made a pen](https://codepen.io/karamanliev/pen/PomQrBx).

```
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
  <section id="sect1" class="page-header has-section-divider">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="section-bg" style="background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/1600/900)"></div>
    <div class="section-dividers">
      <div class="diagonal-divider">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
          <path d="M1200 120L0 16.48 0 0 1200 0 1200 120z" class="shape-fill"></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="sect2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="img" style="background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/500/800)"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>

<style>
#sect1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#sect1 .section-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 10;
}
#sect1 .section-dividers {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 11;
}
#sect1 .section-dividers .diagonal-divider {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
#sect1 .section-dividers .diagonal-divider svg {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% + 1.3px);
  height: 135px;
}
#sect1 .section-dividers .diagonal-divider .shape-fill {
  fill: #ffffff;
}

#sect2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#sect2 .img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -130px;
  right: 200px;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  transform: rotate(16deg);
}`
</style>
```

The problem is that the **SVG section divider** has to be over the **section background**, but under the **image in the next section**. At the same time the **image in the second section** has to be under the **section background** in the first one, so here comes the tricky part. I've tried different combinations of CSS and HTML markup but I can't seem to find any solution.

Edit: I really need to use the SVG dividers for this one, so clip-path is not a solution. Is it even possible with SVG? I have updated [the pen](https://codepen.io/karamanliev/pen/PomQrBx) to be more clear.

Comment: You might be able to achieve this with one element with layered background images. There's some examples on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: I will try, but the image in the 2nd section is actually a slider, so I don't know if that will be possible.

Comment: Ahhh, yeah, I don't think my suggestion will help then.